# Python: long if expression vrs. small if blocks

Tags: python, expression, conditional-statements, pep8

I have this very little and simple if blocks:

```
if obj_type == "domain":
    key = "domain"
elif obj_type == "db_user":
    key = "username"
else:
    key = "name"
```

These can be converted to an if expression:
`key = "domain" if obj_type == "domain" else "usernme" if obj_type == "db_user" else "name"`

Are there any advantages in performance? If that's not a factor, which one should by preferred for readability, PEP8 compliance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They perform identically, so use the first one if you need to choose between the two.

Since you're really just creating a mapping between two sets, using a dictionary would be a better approach. It's faster and arguably more readable:

```
mapping = {
    'domain': 'domain',
    'db_user': 'username',
}

key = mapping.get(obj_type, 'name')
```

Comment: The ``if ... else`` block has a slight advantage of being more convenient for coverage testing.

Comment: Elegant and easily scalable, great!